# Is there a 'da-' construct with 'ohne'? if not, are there any more prepositions that can't form 'da-' constructs

Tags: preposition, compound

I'm talking about "damit, daraus, darauf, darin, da-..."

I've never heard "darohne" or anything like that, and according to the dictionary, nothing like that exists.

Can anyone explain a bit and perhaps give more examples of prepositions that don't form these "da-" words?

Comment: old fashioned : Die christliche Lehre vom innern Gottes-Dienst: in 10 Predigten - 
http://books.google.de/books?id=R3E_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA406&lpg=PA406&dq=%22darohne%22&source=bl&ots=oBpU4SDgVl&sig=KAsn4HW8x3Xq65bYXB4691R37Go&hl=de&sa=X&ei=nUmTUaaGCeuv4QT7moHQAQ&ved=0CIcBEOgBMAk#v=onepage&q=%22darohne%22&f=false

Comment: [Here](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemid=GD00726) are some uses... Sounds like a good old-fashioned german word for poets. Even I, as a native speaker didn't know the word 'til now! ^^

Comment: In the book bummi linked, why is it "GOtt" and not "Gott" throughout?

Comment: @misterben I guess, because *Gott* is a substantive, and it's capitalized independing of it's meaning. But then, which would be the equivalent of capitalizing *god*, as done in many languages? Well, it would be *GOtt*.

Comment: @misterben It's emphasis. The typesetter chose to typeset emphasis by capitalizing (bad practice). As c.p. pointed out, that's not easy with nouns in German, so it got double capitalization (even worse practice).

Answer (score 9):

As bummis link proves the word **darohne** used to exist. So why did it disappear? I can only speculate but speculate I can. 
So the **da** in the **da**-words is like a verbal index finger pointing at whatever is being connected with the preposition. **Ohne** however implies that something is NOT there. Pointing at something that is not there is kind of hard... so maybe that's the reason ;).

As was said in the question, today we would have to say **ohne das/es/**. But I think in many occasions people use just ohne and leave the demonstrative pronoun away. To me, **ohne das/es** sounds weird because it conflicts with the da-words system in my head.

Answer (score 3):

I've been living in Germany for about 2 years and am now approaching fluency in the language. There is no such thing as "darohne", if you want to use it in a Nebensatz, as detraraveller said, it is ohne das, or whatever accusative article you need.

You of course can not use a da compound for any sort of Genetiv preposition:

wegen, deshalb, trotz, etc...

The same goes for "wo" compounds.

German, just like English has a lot of rules, which were made to be broken, so sometimes you just have to learn them and practice like mad! I'd really recommend investing in a good grammar book, especially if you are preparing for a language certificate. [This book, helped me quite a bit](https://shop.hueber.de/de/uebungsgrammatik-fuer-fortgeschrittene.html) though it might be really difficult to buy outside of the EU.

Comment: "deswegen" comes quite close to being a "da + wegen" compound, though.

Answer (score 2):

As a student of German language, from what I know, `darohne` doesn't exist. You have to say `ohne das` etc...

And not directly related to the question but i hope you know that you cannot use da words for humans. You can only use it for non-living things. I would be looking forward to some experienced person answering this question...

Comment: check out the book linked to by @bummi ; apparently that word used to exist

Comment: Without having any idea what *darohne* should express, I'd tend to understand it as an opposite to *damit*. For that reason, I think if you trying to find an existing expression it had to be "ohne dass" with two 's'. Ex: "A: Schreib es auf, damit[=auf dass] du es nicht vergiss. B: Ich hab es mir schon aufgeschrieben, darohne[=ohne dass] du es bemerkt hast.